# local variable optimization in python method

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, methods, python-internals

In the following code, I would like to know if the grade_to_score dictionary will be created every time the method is called?

```
def get_score(grade):
    grade_to_score = {'A': 10, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'F': 0} # step 1
    return grade_to_score.get(grade, -1)
```

also, what is the way to confirm that? I am working with Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. To get around it, you can pass it as a default argument so that it will only be evaluated once:

```
def get_score(grade, grade_to_score = {'A': 10, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'F': 0}):
    return grade_to_score.get(grade, -1)
```

or the better approach:

```
def get_score(grade, grade_to_score = None):
    if grade_to_score == None:
        grade_to_score = {'A': 10, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'F': 0}
    return grade_to_score.get(grade, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question *"what is the way to confirm that?"*, you can check whether the same object is being used each time:

```
def get_score(grade):
    grade_to_score = {'A': 10, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'F': 0} # step 1
    print(id(grade_to_score)) # check object ID
    return grade_to_score.get(grade, -1)
```

Now you can call it:

```
>>> a = get_score("")
50252080
>>> b = get_score("")
50249920
>>> c = get_score("")
50249776
```

A different `id` means a different object, so `grade_to_score` clearly *is* being created anew on each call. Interestingly, this doesn't happen if you call in a `for` loop:

```
>>> for _ in range(3):
    a = get_score("")

50249920
50249920
50249920
>>> scores = [get_score(grade) for grade in "ABC"]
53737032
53737032
53737032
```

Comment: your last code snippet is interesting ... I am still clueless about such behaviour

Comment: @johnsharpe I tried your first code snippet. I am getting the same id on each call. :( Probably id is not the correct way because local variable will always have the same location even if the content assigned to it is changed?

Comment: @comiventor no, that isn't how Python variables/memory management work

Comment: you may be correct but I am still not clear about the reasoning behind the behavior of second code snippet

Comment: @comiventor me neither, frankly - it isn't what I expected to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dictionary is created a-new every time the function is called.

You can make it a global instead, or make it a function default:

```
grade_to_score = {'A': 10, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'F': 0} # step 1


def get_score(grade):
    return grade_to_score.get(grade, -1)
```

or

```
def get_score(grade, grade_to_score={'A': 10, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'F': 0}):
    return grade_to_score.get(grade, -1)
```

In the second case`grade_to_score` is passed into the function as a local, so lookups are (marginally) faster.

In both cases the dictionary literal is executed once, on module import. Note that in both cases, because `grade_to_score` is a mutable dictionary, so any changes you make to it are global, not local to the `get_score()` call.

Comment: Isn't your second code snippet better because local variables lookups are much faster than global or built-in variable lookups?

Comment: @comiventor: Yes, which is why it is often used that way.

Comment: @comiventor: sorry, you can only mark *one* answer as accepted! Glad both I and sshashank124 were of help though. :-)

Comment: sorry @Martjin-Pieters I was also in a dilemma and I chose ssashank124  as i saw his answer first